# Supervisord as CMD in docker image is not run inside gitlab job

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, supervisord

I have an docker image which ends with:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

And as I understand CMD function it should be executed when docker image is runned. And locally it is. But when I use it in gitlab job like this:

```
supervisor-test:
  image: some-image-name
  script:
    - sleep 10
    - supervisorctl status
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
```

it gives:

```
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

I'm not sure if gitlab somehow override cmd of image? And how to achieve to execute cmd of an image automatically in gitlab job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GitLab overrides the command provided to the container; the `CMD` defined in your image won't be executed. The command is how GitLab sets up your job container for executing the job script.

> how to achieve to execute cmd of an image automatically in gitlab job

You can use `ENTRYPOINT` of your image to ensure execution of a command automatically in GitLab CI, but your entrypoint must then be prepared to run the shell script passed as the command (e.g. use `exec /bin/bash` at the end of your entrypoint, if the entrypoint is a bash script).

If you need different behaviors for the image when executing in CI, you can condition this based on the presence of the `$CI` environment variable or any other [pre-defined](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) or user-defined environment variable in your job.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# my-entrypoint script
echo "doing something before running commands"

if [[ -n "$CI" ]]; then
    echo "this block will only execute in a CI environment"
    supervisorctl restart all || echo "could not restart" # or whatever you want
    echo "now running script commands"
    # this is how GitLab expects your entrypoint to end, if provided
    # will execute scripts from stdin
    exec /bin/bash

else
    echo "this block will only execute in NON-CI environments"
    # execute the command as if passed to the container normally
    exec "$@"
fi
```

Then in your dockerfile you may do something like this:

```
COPY my-entrypoint /my-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /my-entrypoint # Optional if you set executable bit in filesystem
ENTRYPOINT ["/my-entrypoint"]
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"] # the default command, when no other is provided
```

Note that it's possible to override the entrypoint as part of your GitLab configuration as well:

```yaml
my_job:
  image:
    name: "python:3.9-slim"
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo this executed before the job; exec /bin/bash"]
  script:
    - echo "hello"
    - "echo 123"
```

The ability to override the entrypoint can be disabled in the runner configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add supervisord as service for your job.